# Prove that $d\le{(xy+yz+xz)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $x,y,z$ be positive integers such that $\frac{x+1}{y}+\frac{y+1}{z}+\frac{z+1}{x}$ is an integer. Let $d$ be the greatest common divisor of $x,y,z$. Prove that

$$d\le{(xy+yz+xz)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$.

I have no idea how to proceed in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, $$\sum _{ cyc }^{  }{ f(a,b,c) }=f(a,b,c)+f(b,c,a)+f(c,a,b)$$

Notice that the equation abve becomes $$\frac{\sum _{ cyc }^{  }{ x^{ 2 }y } +\sum _{ cyc }^{  }{ xy }}{xyz}$$.

However, because $d^3$ divides both $\sum _{ cyc }^{  }{ x^{ 2 }y}$
and $xyz$, $d^3$ must divide $${\sum _{ cyc }^{  }{ xy }}$$
for the equation to be a interger.

This implies that $d^3 \le \sum _{ cyc }^{  }{ xy }$